# сортировка данных в mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, на форуме нужно вывести темы:

а) закрепленные(topic_position = 0) 
 б) все остальные где последний timestamp - те в первую очередь и т.д.

Пытался сделать это таким способом:

```
    $query_position = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT topic_position FROM topics WHERE forum_id = '$forum_id'");                        //Считываем прикрепленная ли тема

  while ($row_position = mysqli_fetch_array($query_position)) 
  {
   if ($row_position['topic_position'] == 1)    //Если тема не прикрепленная
   $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id = '$forum_id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC"); 
   elseif ($row_position['topic_position'] == 0) //Если прикрепленная
   $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id = '$forum_id' ORDER BY topic_position ASC, timestamp DESC");
  }
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
   {
     //Вывод тем
   }
```

Понимаю, что в запросе ошибка, но вот какая - не могу понять. Помогите, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем столько запросов к базе, да еще и в цикле?
Не проще все делать одним:

```
SELECT *
FROM topics
WHERE forum_id = 1
ORDER BY (topic_position != 0), timestamp DESC
```

Он и топики выведет, и отсортирует все как положено. Принцип сортировки: вначале закрепленные, затем по дате-времени. `(topic_position != 0)` - условие, и может быть два варианта 0 и 1. 0 - если топик закреплен, 1 - если нет.

**UPD:** `(topic_position != 0)` нужно только в том случае если `topic_position`  может принимать несколько значений, а не только 0 и 1, и в сортировке остальные значения учитывать не нужно. Если только 0 и 1, то - достаточно:

```
ORDER BY topic_position, timestamp DESC
```

Comment: спасибо, что-то я действительно намудрил :)